# Rubygems - where are the package downloaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When you install a new package, for example, 'gem install fb-graph', where are the files downloaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this command to find where a particular gem is installed:

```
gem which <gem_name>
```

For example:

```
gem which fb-graph
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ gem environment
```

This will spit out information that will tell you where things are being installed.

Answer (score 4):

as @Philip suggested, use `gem environment` to see default locations.

if you need to install in custom folder, set `GEM_HOME` variable:

```
export GEM_HOME=~/gems
gem install fb-graph
```

will install `fb-graph` in your home dir, in `gems/` folder

to persist this, put `export GEM_HOME=/path/to/gems` in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file